# Calculating anti-aliasing on a grid of points

Tags: javascript, image, algorithm, html5-canvas

I'm representing an image by a list of integers representing the intensity of each pixel in an image. Each point is either 0 or 1. Given this data, how can I calculate the antialiased values so the final result is smooth?

Example data:

```
// What I have
const aliased = [
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
   0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
   0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
   0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
];

// What I want to calculate
const smoothed = [
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
   0, 0, 1, 0, 0.5, // <- point with intensity of 50%
   0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
   0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
   0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
];
```

## Current input

[image]

## Desired output

[image]

Comment: What method are you using for render the current output? Share your code please

Comment: Let's say I'm rendering a `NxN` pixel `<div>` for each point, and setting the background color to a value between 0-255 based on the input value (`(val) => val / 255`). I'm wanting to calculate the antialiasing by hand, and not just leverage `<canvas>` to do it for me.

Comment: You can draw the points on the canvas with the color and opacity you like. Simply, share your code, we don't write code for you, we only help you to solve your specific programming problems.

Comment: The problem isn't plotting the data. What I'm trying to solve is calculating where the anti-aliased points go, and what values they should have.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that changes the things. But I can't help you on this task, sorry. I wish someone have an idea. Good luck!

Comment: Take the original input and do either box or gaussian blurring. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur